# Error soapResponse Exception SpringBusFactory

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jbpm

I'm trying to consume a soap web service in Java, it only work with eclipse IDE, but does not work when to import JBPM project. The error I get is:

> Failed to determine BusFactory implementation class name: java.lang.ClassCastException : class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory

It works perfecly with Eclipse

[image]
My source code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
public class metodos {
 public metodos() {
    super();
 }

public String getInfo() {
    String retorno = "";
    System.out.println("methodGetInfo ");
    try {
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo newInstance");
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo createConnection");
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo MessageFactory newInstance");
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo createMessage");
        javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage soapRequest = messageFactory.createMessage();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo getSOAPPart");
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapRequest.getSOAPPart();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo getEnvelope");
        SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("end", endPoint);
        SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
        soapBody.addChildElement("getInfo", "end");
        soapRequest.saveChanges();

        System.out.println("methodGetInfo soapConnection call");
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, url);
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo transformerFactory");
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo newTransformer");
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo getSOAPPart");
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();

        System.out.println("methodGetInfo StringWriter");
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo StreamResult");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        System.out.println("methodGetInfo transformer.transform");
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
```

When I use JBPM I get this error:

[image: JPBMERROR]

The error is caused by this line:

> SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequest, url);

I´not using any external libraries in java.

Java compiler leve:1.8

JBPM version: 7.17.0 Final

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two different versions of apache cxf available, one from EAP module and a different version from jbpm application war/lib folders. You will have to disable  one of these jars to resolve this conflict.